# $state.go not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

$state.go not working.
I don't know why..

> template

```
<td class="text-center">
    <button class="button button-small" ng-repeat="item2 in studentList" ng-if="item.id == item2.id" ng-click="studentDetailgo(item2.id, item2.col_code, item2.major_code, 2017, 2)">Detail
    </button>
</td>
```

> controller

```
$scope.studentDetailgo= function(id, col_code, major_code, year, season) {
    console.log(1);
    $state.go('studentDetailgo', {
        "id": id,
        "col_code": col_code,           
        "major_code": major_code,
        "year": year,
        "season": season
    });
    console.log(2);
}
```

log(1), log(2) Output. but $state.go not working

> app.js

```
.state('studentDetailgo', {
    url: '/studentDetailgo/:id/:col_code/:major_code/:year/:season',
    views: {
        'mileage': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/searchDetail.html',
            controller: 'MileageStudentDetailCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

what should I do....

Comment: Did you inject `$state` in the controller definition?

Comment: .controller('MileageDetailCtrl', function($cordovaToast, $cordovaDialogs, $rootScope, $state, ...)  
I injected ti into the controller

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors on console other than console.log?

Comment: There is no error except console.log.

Answer (score 0):

```
I already check your routing its right 

.state('studentDetailgo', {
    url: '/studentDetailgo/:id/:col_code/:major_code/:year/:season',
    views: {
        'mileage': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/searchDetail.html',
            controller: 'MileageStudentDetailCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

also check your controller scope function it also right.

May be you don't inject **$state** in this controller or you don't inject **$stateParams** to get those value in **MileageStudentDetailCtrl** controller

Comment: .controller('MileageStudentDetailCtrl, function($scope, $stateParams, $rootScope) 
 It is injected in this way. Click event in modal window.

Comment: can u paste code in MileageStudentDetailCtrl as well as from where it called controller

Comment: I tried it the other way. 
<a ui-sref="studentDetailgo({id:item2.id, col_code:item2.col_code, major_code:item2.major_code,year:2017,season:2})">
This also does not work.

Comment: if  $state.go not working definitely ui-sref not working ..... so update code or provide git like i will try to fix this

Comment: I am collaborating on one project. But in other parts $state.go and ui-sref work. However, only the code I wrote does not work. It is crazy...
I use ui-sref in a modal window. Is this a problem??